# Android Bluetooth Increase Speed Performance

Tags: android, performance, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am trying to increase the transfer speed on android bluetooth. I experimented transferring a 2.7MB buffer from one android device to another using RFComm socket of the Bluetooth API (see code below). It took ~70 secs to complete. I compared this method against the "Share" via bluetooth function that came with the phone. The "Share" function gave exceptionally better performance (~15 secs to transfer a 2.7MB file).

How does the "Share" function differ from using the Bluetooth API? How can I replicate the "Share" method to get optimized transfer speed?

Thanks,

Bluetooth API test code:

Server side - installed on one android device

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
mServerSocket = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("DeviceName", MY_UUID);
socket = mServerSocket.accept();
mInStream = socket.getInputStream();
int totalByte = 1;
while (totalByte < 2718720) 
{
    int bytesAvailable = mInStream.available();
    if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
        totalByte += bytesAvailable;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesAvailable];
        mInStream.read(buffer);
    }
}
```

Client side - installed on other android device

```
mClientSocket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                MY_UUID);
mClientSocket.connect();
mOutStream = mClientSocket.getOutputStream();
byte byteValue = 0;
for (int i=0; i<2718720; i++) {
    byteValue++;
    mOutStream.write(byteValue);
}
```

Comment: Do this using an object push profile (OPP) or if you want bi-directional file operations use (FTP) instead of RFComm

Comment: Did you ever figure out the reason?